# ¿Cómo puedo crear en r un dataframe a partir de otro con dos columnas indicando la posición de la fila y la columna en el que se encuentra cada valor?

Tags: r, dataframe

Quiero crear a partir de un dataframe, otro dataframe con tres columnas: una con los valores del primer dataframe, otra con la posición de la columna en la que se encuentra el valor en el primer dataframe otra con la posición de la fila en la que se encuentra el valor en el primer dataframe.

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente imagen, la primera tabla es el dataframe cargado en r y la tabla de la derecha es el resultado que quiero obtener.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Agrega por favor a tu pregunta lo que hayas intentado hacer  hasta ahora, eso hace que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por l comunidad. Saludos.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿solo tienes 8 filas? ¿Qué pasa si tuvieras más de 27 filas? ¿Cómo se nombrarían?

Comment: Con los dataframes que estoy trabajando siempre tendré 8 filas, el problema es que puedo tener más columnas y de la forma que lo estaba haciendo con muchas columnas se complicaba. Por ello buscaba otra manera de hacerlo. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lo conceptual, la solución es similar a la de César:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(fila = LETTERS[1:nrow(.)]) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-fila) %>% 
  separate(name, into=c('X', 'columna'), sep=1) %>% 
  select(ID=value, columna, fila)

# A tibble: 24 x 3
      ID columna fila 
   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
 1  2871 1       A    
 2  2871 2       A    
 3  2871 3       A    
 4  3039 1       B    
 5  3039 2       B    
 6  3039 3       B    
 7  1411 1       C    
 8  1411 2       C    
 9  1411 3       C    
10  1855 1       D    
# ... with 14 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comentarios:

- Primero generamos una columna para indicar el nombre de la fila (Solo aplicable si tienes hasta 26 filas
- Luego usamos `pivot_longer` para expandir a lo largo el `data.frame`, lo que nos deja la estructura casi idéntica a lo que buscas
- Lo que resta son cambios estéticos, como recuperar el número de fila de la `X*` y ordenar las columnas con los nombres apropiados

Answer (score 2):

Lo que haría sería hacer una transformación. Para ello usaría el paquete tidyr.
Específicamente con la función `gather()`

```
df<-data.frame(fila=c(LETTERS[1:8]),
               x1=c(2871,3039,1411,1855,2871,3039,1411,1855),
               x2=c(2871,3039,1411,1855,2871,3039,1411,1855),
               x3=c(2871,3039,1411,1855,2871,3039,1411,1855))

> df
  fila   x1   x2   x3
1    A 2871 2871 2871
2    B 3039 3039 3039
3    C 1411 1411 1411
4    D 1855 1855 1855
5    E 2871 2871 2871
6    F 3039 3039 3039
7    G 1411 1411 1411
8    H 1855 1855 1855
```

Aplicando `gather()`, el cual pide el nombre de la columna que contiene a las variables que pasan a ser en formato largo, en este caso los ID, luego te pide el nombre de la columna que tendrá el valor de estas columnas que van a formato largo, en tu caso `COLUMNA`. Por último, las columnas que se transformarán que son desde la segunda a la cuarta.

```
df %>% gather(ID, COLUMNA, 2:4) %>% arrange(fila)
```

El resultado.

```
   fila ID COLUMNA
1     A x1    2871
2     A x2    2871
3     A x3    2871
4     B x1    3039
5     B x2    3039
6     B x3    3039
7     C x1    1411
8     C x2    1411
9     C x3    1411
10    D x1    1855
11    D x2    1855
12    D x3    1855
13    E x1    2871
14    E x2    2871
15    E x3    2871
16    F x1    3039
17    F x2    3039
18    F x3    3039
19    G x1    1411
20    G x2    1411
21    G x3    1411
22    H x1    1855
23    H x2    1855
24    H x3    1855
```